# Match objects that have a list containing a particular String With Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Imagine I have a class called `SomeClass` which has a list of Strings called `aStringList`.

```
public Class SomeClass{

  List<String> aStringList;

  ...

}
```

I want to find all the objects of SomeClass such that `aStringList` contains a String `"sillyString"`.

I have tried:

```
Datastore ds = Dao.instance().getDatabase();
List<String> myResults = ds.find(SomeClass.class).
field("aStringList").hasThisElement("sillyString").asList();
```

However that gives me the error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoException: invalid parameter: expected an object ($elemMatch)
```

Comment: Have you already tried the simple ``field(...).equal(...)`` (assuming you are looking for an exact match)? And why the double post?

Comment: Are you sure, that _aStringList_ was saved to DB as array? Doublecheck this pls.

Comment: @xeraa I just tried field(...).equal(...) and it actually works? I don't think it makes sense logically, but if they've decided to make it work then I won't complain. If you would like to write it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `field(...).equal(...)` (assuming you are looking for an exact match). MongoDB will match both single values as well as any value inside an array.

Use `.hasThisElement(...)` if you have a list of custom document entities (`@Reference List<MyEntity>`) and you want to check if a specific one is being referenced.